# increment css in javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 'span' tags and each span i need to increment 'left' property by 10px.

Ex:-

```
CSS:
span.cell_0     {   left:   0px;       }
span.cell_1     {   left:   10px;      }
span.cell_2     {   left:   20px;      }
HTML:
<span class="cell_0">name</span>
<span class="cell_1">#</span>
```

i have javascript written as:

```
$( 'span' ).css( 'left', '+=10px' );
```

but am trying for each span

Am designing layout; rows and columns.

```
<div class="row1">
 <span class="cell_0">name</span>
 <span class="cell_1">#</span>
</div>
<div class="row2">
 <span class="cell_0">name</span>
 <span class="cell_1">#</span>
</div>
```

CSS for rows:

```
.row1, .row2, .row3, .row4{
font-size:12px;
padding:5px 20px 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: And you haven't written a single line of javascript to start with ?

Comment: Do you want to increment it on `click`, on `hover`, on `load`?

Comment: @bborisovs yes it is onload (kind of am designing layout)

Comment: @jeromesmadja i have written; i lost the javascript while posting. some editing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do with what you've given

```
$('span.[class^="cell_"]').each(function(i,v){ // loop through each span with class that starts with cell_
   var num = +$(v).attr('class').split('_')[1]; // get the number from the class
   $(v).css('left',(num * 10) + 'px') // use it to get the px
});
```

Comment: eh.. not too worried.  Just want to help :)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I would say you should apply a class to the divs in question:

```
<div class="indent">
   <span class="cell_0">name</span>
   <span class="cell_1">#</span>
</div>
<div class="indent">
   <span class="cell_0">name</span>
   <span class="cell_1">#</span>
</div>

$('.indent').each(function(){
    $(this).find('span').each(function(i, v){
         $(this).css('left', (i * 10) + 'px');
    });
});
```

That's one way to do it. I don't know what you're doing with the classes assigned to each span. But if it is for the sake of trying to indent, you can just remove the classes from span and let the generic selector do the work for you.

Comment: You were faster than me. but yes it is as simple as that.

Comment: that's under the assumption that he doesn't have any other spans on his page

Comment: You're too nice, I wanted him to give us at least something to show us that he's tried.

Comment: I know. I should have voted to close but I was bored... or something. Notice I didn't bother using v... that's my revenge I guess.

Comment: @wirey - true, but he said "each span." He should just apply a single class to all that need this attention but we don't know what he's up to or what he really needs. I'm actually surprised this many of us felt the need to give this kind of attention to this thread. we're all too kind

Comment: @Kai Qing Just trying to get last upvote for the daily cap :)

Comment: @VMAtm - lol. there you go. I noticed you abandoned v as well. We both get our revenge.

Comment: @KaiQing I have to indent for rows & columns.  I have to indent particular number; but you got my need of "indent" My purpose solved with responses from you and wirey.  I do have some edits; but this solves my major issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select only needed spans by class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[class^=cell]'").each(function(i, v){
        $(this).css('left', (i * 10) + 'px');
    });      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a frame work like jquery/prototype to select the spans from the html?
You can just use document.getElementsByTagName('span') then just loop them and increment the property (left)